# How to change tooltip with jQuery highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to have my tooltips display my `y` value instead of the percentage they currently do. For example, when hovering over `Yellow`, the tooltip reads `22.6%`. It should instead read `91.5` yellow skittles.

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false
        },
        title: { text: 'Skittles By Color' },
        subtitle: { text: '15.4 oz (437 g) Bag' },
        tooltip: { pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>' },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                    style: { color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black' },
                    connectorColor: 'silver'
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Color %',
            data: [
                { name: 'Green', y: 64, sliced: true, selected: true, color: '#00ff00'}, 
                { name: 'Purple', y: 71, color: '#660066' },
                { name: 'Red', y: 88.0, color: '#dd0000' },
                { name: 'Orange', y: 91, color: '#ff6600' },
                { name: 'Yellow', y: 91.5, color: '#ffff00' }
            ]
        }]
    });
});
```

## [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jpotLvt7/8/)

Comment: Hi,Thank you.  I got it working with help from another use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you see the `tooltip` section in your code?  That's what you need to change:

```
pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
```

...should be...

```
pointFormat: '<b>{point.y} skittles</b>'
```

As demonstrated here: http://jsfiddle.net/jpotLvt7/11/.

When you have problems like this in the future, I'd recommend looking in your code to see if there are any parts that have names relevant to your issue.  In this case, it wasn't too hard to find.  You wanted to change the tooltip text, and there was a `tooltip { ... }` part of your code.

Comment: This is sweet, thank you.  I did try and change the tooltip, but was unsuccessful.

Comment: Glad I could help, and thanks for accepting the answer!  If you wouldn't mind up-voting it as well if you found it useful, I'd appreciate it.